# Фоновая подгрузка страницы черезе iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые знатоки.

просто замечательная штука этот фрейм, позволяет фоном загрузить страницу. Есть проблема, если на подгружаемой странице стоит видео с ютуба на автопроигрывании, то фоном начинают звучать звуки с видео.
Как сделать так, чтобы этого не происходило?
пробовал display:none - не помогает :(

Answer (score 0):

В `videoId` вставьте свой идентификатор видео.

```js
 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  var player;
  player = new YT.Player('muteYouTubeVideoPlayer', {
    videoId: 'CBprH6ueM9U', // YouTube Video ID
    width: 560,               // Player width (in px)
    height: 316,              // Player height (in px)
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 1,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
      loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
      fs: 0,              // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
    },
    events: {
      onReady: function(e) {
        e.target.mute();
      }
    }
  });
 }

 // Written by @labnol
```

```html
<div id="muteYouTubeVideoPlayer"></div>
<script async src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызов `play()` на тэге `<video>` в последних версиях браузеров позвращает `promise`. Если видео проигрывается - получаем `resolve`, если нет, - `reject` (+ дает детальную ошибку)

```
var playerPromise = document.querySelector('videoFrame').play(),
    player = document.querySelector('videoFrame');

if (playerPromise !== undefined) {
  playerPromise.then(function() {
     // если проигрывание стоит на автомате
     player.stop();
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // не проигрывается. Тут можно вызвать событие клика на кнопку проигрывания, для триггера 
     document.querySelector('youtubePlayButton').addEventListener('click',function(){
       player.play();
     });
  });
}
```